# Replace pixels with symbols

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to write a function that would take an indexed image as an input and will replace all its pixels by symbols or characters.

An image is worth more than a 1000 words: This is the desired look output. Each of the symbols represent an unique color value of the image.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to print in the screen the symbols in the correct place. My first approach has been to use the "Wingdings" font and to put text on the places, but does not work as expected. The text changes sizes when zoomed, and does not behave accordingly to the rest of the plot.

I leave here a small piece of code that creates a small grid and uses an example image.

```
function drawChars (img)
if nargin==0
    load mandrill
    img=X(1:4:end,1:4:end);
end


chars=randperm(numel(unique(img)));

[h,w]=size(img);
% Form a grid
figure
hold on
for ii=0:h
   plot([ii ii],[0 w],'k');
end
for ii=0:w
   plot([0 h],[ii ii],'k');
end
axis equal;
axis([0 h 0 w])

%% This does not work as expected
for ii=1:h
    for jj=1:w
        text(ii, jj, char(chars(img(ii,jj))), 'fontname', 'Wingdings', 'fontsize',10);
    end
end

end
```

Short question: What approach would you use to solve the problem?

NOTE: there is a problem with the choice of chars also, but ignore it for the time being (if char { is chosen does not work nicely)

Comment: What's your desired output? Raster/Vector graphics?

Comment: @knedlsepp Good point. Yeah, for example. Actually whatever than could be later printed. Additionally it would be nice if I could breack it into part manually. Thats why I started with this approach, so I could zoom as I pleased and save pieces of it.

Comment: I guess the simplest approach would be to use a monospaced font and just output a string as in [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Comment: @knedlsepp Interesting. Any suggestion on an symbolic monospaced font?

Comment: @knedlsepp While it may work, if I do that I cant form a grid or some other  aesthetically more pleasant things that I may want to do.

Comment: Indeed; I also don't know of any symbolic monospaced fonts off the top of my head. You could however export it as a CSV-file and then pretty print it with Excel or some similar software as a workaround. (Which might even work for non-monospaced fonts)

Comment: If you really want to do it in MATLAB you could generate equally sized raster-representations of your symbols and put them all in a cell array. Then you could probably use linear indexing and `cat`. There's also the option [`'FontUnits'`,`'normalized'`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) for a text to change the zoom behavior if you want to use `text`.

Answer (score 0):

With `figure` changed to `f=figure`

```
r=size(img).*16;
set(f,'paperunits','points')
set(f,'papersize',r)
set(f,'paperposition',[0 0 r]);
print(f,'example.png','-dpng');
```

Prints the created figure to a png of sufficient size.

Comment: This is nice, but work if you already have the figure and you want to plot it. However, my problem relies more  into assigning aesthetically correctly (e.g. the middle of the symbol centred with the middle of the pixel) the symbol to the pixel. Seing how `text` works probably to get a nice image I just need another approach. But thanks for this nice piece of code!